# how to make a wide design website fit into the browser width

Tags: css, width, scrollbar, psd

I have a PSD design full of gradients(top-bottom-left-right) and I have to use CSS 2, so I have to cut a big part of background fully. But some of the images are too wide (1920px)and I don't want want the scroll-bars. Is there a way to make the image fit to the screen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There some tricks are there like you can use image in `<img>` tag & give `width:100% , height:100%`

check this http://csswizardry.com/2011/07/responsive-images-right-now/

**OR**

there is a `filter` for IE for image stretch

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/background-photo.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Check this for more http://www.paulmccrodden.com/blog/ie-problems-css3-039background-size-cover039-and-iefilters

Comment: It was really helpful but it didn't solve my problem. The scroll-bar has disappeared now, but when the browser is on the normal mode the right  part of the image is not visible. My proble is that my image is really big, I need to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make your image the body background?